# ERROR: Could not find GNU compatible version of 'tar' command while installing RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, gnu

I'm trying to follow the instructions in this post: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/

To install Ruby on my Mac. However I get this error:

```
RyanT:~$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15790  100 15790    0     0  14754      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 14754

ERROR: Could not find GNU compatible version of 'tar' command, make sure it's available first before continuing installation.
```

I did run this:

```
brew install gnu-tar --default-names
```

Having found the command in a stray blog post about GNU. However it's not helped.

Searching Google I can't find anyone else who's had this error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a bug and should be fixed with: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/b6e3993614b3cad50d5b0336f80c693fabafa6e0

if it still hapens open rvm issue here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues